# Gewollte oder beiläufige Verwendung von Wort- bzw. Präfixpaaren

Tags: style, technical-terminology

Neulich im Radio:

> Er ist für die Linkspartei im Rechtsausschuss.

Hat dieses Phänomen einen Namen?
(Unfreiwillige Komik zumindest scheint es mir zu sein.)

*Andere Beispiele*

> *(Bildbeschreibung)* Im Hintergrund ein Vorderlader
>
> *(Streit zwischen Mietern)* Nachspiel im Vorgarten
>
> »Wer hat den Unfall verursacht?« – »Ein Großhändler im Kleinwagen.«
>
> »Wer ist gestern im Suff mit grölenden Horden durch die Stadt
>   gezogen?« – »Ein Oberinspektor im Unterhemd.«

Answer (score 2):

Es ähnelt einer [Antithese](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithese). Während diese jedoch beabsichtigt und oft zusätzlich stilistisch markiert ist ("Die Kunst ist lang. Und kurz ist unser Leben" - Goethe -, hier als Chiasmus), sind die oben genannten Beispiele entweder unbeabsichtigt oder, wie multiplex schrieb, Wortspiele mit semantischen Oppositionen. Viele sind als Zwillingsformeln lexikalisiert (Groß und Klein, Jung und Alt, der Anfang vom Ende, Anspruch und Wirklichkeit...).

Answer (score -1):

> Hat dieses Phänomen einen Namen?

Nein, es gibt keine spezifisch grammatikalische Bezeichnung für das von Dir beschriebene Phänomen.

Die Komik entsteht aus dem Kontext, und dem Wortwitz/Wortspiel.

Comment: Ich kann mir zwar vorstellen, dass das Kind wirklich keinen Namen hat, aber nur, weil ich keinen kenne bedeutet das ja nicht, dass Profilinguisten auch keinen kennen. Was macht Dich sicher, dass es keinen gibt? Der letzte Satz trägt auch nichts zur Wahrheitsfindung bei und ist für den Frager sicher auch nichts neues.